# Applescript Copy file to a current folder

Tags: applescript

I am total nube.
Would like to ask you how to write an applescript to Copy file to a current folder.

Actually I understand how to copy File from one destination to other

```
tell application "Finder" to copy file "HDD/ ../Location/filename" to folder "HDD/.../Destination"
```

But how to get file to an active window?

I could only read the current location by

```
tell application "Finder" to get (the target of the front window)
```

But what should be after it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all `file "HDD/ ../Location/filename"` won't work because the Finder doesn't know slash separated POSIX paths. It supports only colon separated HFS paths starting with a disk name.

Second of all the command `copy` assigns a value to a variable. The proper command to **copy** items in the Finder is `duplicate`.

You can write

```
tell application "Finder"
    try -- ignores an error if no window is open
        set destinationFolder to target of the front window
        duplicate file "HDD: ..:Location:filename" to destinationFolder
    end try
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you for a prompt reply. Will try it and let you know. Thank you one more time